# Get the solr indexed response without updating the solr index in use

Tags: indexing, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I want the final object that is sent to the *Solr* server. There is a third-party that wants the same exact data but they want it directly from *Hybris* (right now they are getting it from *Solr* server itself).
If I run the indexing job it will update the current *Solr* indexes. I don't want to update the *Solr* index.

I need to send the response as `List<ProdutData>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the magic happens-

```
SolrInputDocument solrDocument = this.createInputDocument(itemModel, indexConfig, indexedType);
```

in

> /hybris/bin/ext-commerce/solrfacetsearch/bin/solrfacetsearchserver.jar!/de/hybris/platform/solrfacetsearch/indexer/impl/DefaultIndexer.class:174